# Custom search in wordpress for all and custom post both

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I want option for all search and custom post type in search bar . I have done for custom post search but when i search for all then comes error and not working.Please see image and code.
 [image]

Searching is working for both custom post type. But when i search for all then its showing error. Please see below my code.

```
function mySearchFilter($query){$post_type = $_GET['searchfrom'];
if($post_type != 'all')
{
    if ($query->is_search)
    {
        if (!empty($post_type)) {
            $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        }
    }
}
else 
{
    $query->set();
}

return $query;}
```

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');

Please let me know about the else condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mySearchFilter($query){
$post_type = $_GET['searchfrom'];
if($post_type != 'all')
{
    if ($query->is_search())
    {
        if (!empty($post_type)) {
            $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        }
    }
}

return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```